# Timing of section 'Bucketing' after Ajax Request in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

After performing an ajax request to Sitecore controller, in the response there is always a text "Timing of section 'Bucketing':" added to the response by Sitecore. Under the hood I'm indeed creating new Bucket and putting items in there but I don't add any messages by myself. Would you help me with getting rid of the message being included in the response?

Kind Regards

Comment: You might have Sitecore Debugger activated which is appending debug output to your controller's response. Try again after clearing cookies.